# How to extract value from json object response in postman

Tags: json, postman

I got this response :

```
"success": true,
    "data": {
        "638f2a029a8253170d1272c7": {
            ...
            "id": "638f2a029a8253170d1272c7",    // this is the value i want
            "permissions": {
                ...
            }
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

the value I want is the id:  `"id": "638f2a029a8253170d1272c7"`

I tried this:

```
let responseData = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("customerid", responseData.data[0].id);`
```

but getting error

Comment: if you have id you can get it like: `res.data['yourId']`. otherwise you can use `Object.entries()`

Comment: data is not an array, so you can't do data[n]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct code would be:

```js
let responseData = pm.response.json(); 

//get the first key of `data` object --> the `id` you want
pm.environment.set("customerid", Object.keys(responseData.data)[0]);
//638f2a029a8253170d1272c7
```

Answer (score -1):

you can get the id field value from JSON in this way.

**JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(responseJson);
System.out.println(jsonObj.getString("id));**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).